# Eclipse: Blackberry simulator output console is not showing any entry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

Suddenly the console is showing no output while I run my programs on the simulator(even when on debug mode).
The console remains all empty while I start the simulator and run the programs.
How to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might sound stupid, but have you restarted Eclipse? I've seen this happen before and I've just restarted